# Set selected option focused JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need do set an option from the list, selected and visible in dropdown. 
I had this code:

```
/* some js....*/
........
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: url,
    data : mydata,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#format_type option').removeAttr('selected')
        $('#format_type option:eq('+data+')').attr('selected', true);
        $('#format_type option:selected').focus();
    }
});

..............
```

The html code:

```
echo "<select name='format_type' id='format_type'>";
echo "<option value='1'>Fixed</toption>";
echo "<option value='2'>Year Digit 4[Y---]</toption>";
echo "<option value='3'>Year Digit 3[-Y--]</toption>";
echo "<option value='4'>Year Digit 2[--Y-]</toption>";
echo "<option value='5'>Year Digit 1[---Y]</toption>";
echo "<option value='6'>Month Digit 2[M-]</toption>";
echo "<option value='7'>Month Digit 1[-M]</toption>";
.............
```

The jquery code does function very well, after the ajax response, the option requested is selected (i saw that in Inspect Element), but the list stays as it was, the options 'Fixed' stays the first and when I click on the list, none of options below is selected (although at Inspect Element it has `selected='selected'`).
This is how it looks after ajax response:
[image]

Please anybody help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `data` gives the index of the option; Using `prop` instead of `attr` might help

```
 $('#format_type option:eq('+data+')').prop('selected', true);
```

Instead of

```
$('#format_type option').removeAttr('selected')
$('#format_type option:eq('+data+')').attr('selected', true);
```